# Can't assign new value in array in Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having problems with my Firebase function, I am getting a collection from Firestore, and trying to change its value locally in nodejs (not uploading it back to Firestore), yet the value stays the same, try/catch is not returning any errors.
Here is my code:

```
function setValueInArray(indexArray, array) {
console.log("SetValueInArray");
   for (var index of indexArray) {
       console.log(array[index].data().value); // **Logs false**
       console.log("_________");
       array[index].data().value = true;
       console.log(array[index].data().value); // **Logs false**
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the Object returned by the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot?authuser=0#data) method. You have to assign it to a new Object, as follows:

```
  function setValueInArray(indexArray, array) {
    console.log('SetValueInArray');
    for (var index of indexArray) {
      var newObj = array[index].data();
      console.log(newObj.value); // **Logs false**
      newObj.value = true;
      console.log(newObj.value); // **Logs true**
    }
  }
```